# Web transforms not transforming in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-config, config-transformation

**Question:** How do I enforce default VS publishing behavior to force VS 2012 to only deploy a transformed `web.release.config` file as a `web.config` file?

**Context:** I have a VS 2012 solution containing three projects, all of which use web transforms.

**Problem:** One of the projects, when publishing to the file system, instead of publishing the `web.config` file for the *designated configuration* (`web.release.config`), publishes ALL variations of the `web.config` files (`web.config`, `web.debug.config`, `web.release.config`) to the target directory.

**Consequence:** The web server defaults to using the raw (un-transformed) `web.config`, instead of the intended `web.release.config` transformed into a solitary `web.config`. This necessitates manual intervention to rename a manually-transformed `web.release.config` as `web.config`. Neither of the other two projects in the solution exhibits this anomalous behavior.